# Arranging numbers in a four by four arrangement

Tags: c

My assignment is: Write a program that asks the user to enter number 1-16 in any order, and then display those numbers in a 4 by 4 arrangement. My program compiles and runs, but when it runs, it displays this:

```
num2 num5 num 7 num9
num3 num16 num15 num14
num4 num6 num8 num10
num12 num11 num 13 num1
```

Instead of:

```
15 16 2 1
3 5 7 9
6 8 10 11
13 12 14 4
```

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16;

printf ( "Enter number 1-16 in any order: ");

scanf ( "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4, &num5, &num6, &num7, &num8, &num9, &num10, &num11, &num12, &num13, &num14, &num15, &num16);

printf ( "%d%d%d%d\t%d%d%d%d\t%d%d%d%d\t%d%d%d%d",num1,num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16);

return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? T

I have to use this with simple functions,and not with arrays and loops.

I have to find row/diagonal/column sum.

Comment: what is `"… n` there should be `,` it don't compile

Comment: Why don't you use array and loops? BTW, there is no way it's displaying the output you posted.

Comment: Besides the obvious error with the dots after the format string, there is no way you could get it to output the strings `num2` etc. Unless it's not the real code you're showing... Also, if you want to display stuff on different lines, adding newlines to the output might be a good idea.

Comment: also, that \t isn't going to go down a line. u need \n instead. \t is for tab, i think 4 white spaces

Comment: still isnt correct...

Comment: Apart from the glaring errors. How are you providing the input? In its current form,there is no way the code can output that.

Comment: I mean,now my program only arranges the rows four by four,how about the row/column/diagonal sums?

Comment: @Notyourthing Edit your question to show a sample input

Comment: @Notyourthing Use loops and print the arrays use to store the numbers.

Comment: No,I cant use the arrays...thats what it said in my assignement,no loops and arrays..

Comment: @Notyourthing Then it becomes kind of a no-brainer.

Comment: Be nice to me,it's my first time.

Comment: I finally figured this out.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first part of the question already has been solved I'm just adding for the row/col/diag sum bit which you can do like this:

```
int sum_row1 = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4);
int sum_row2 = (num5 + num6 + num7 + num8);

int sum_col1 = (num1 + num5 + num9 + num13);
int sum_col2 = (num2 + num6 + num10 + num14);
```

Do this after you've read the digits and add to the printf statement at appropriate places.

I didn't include the diagonal as I'm not sure what you want, but I guess you see the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Use something like this**

```
printf ( "%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d",num1,num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16);
```

You are using `\t` which is used for horizontal spacing,
Use `\n` instead,it will take you to the next line...
output for 1 digit no's will be like this

```
5 6 7 8
8 9 0 1
1 2 3 4
```

Now use this and extend it for than 1 digit inputs...
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Learner,I already edited that,have a look again please :) Now,the problem is that now my program only arranges the rows four by four,how about the row/column/diagonal sums?

Comment: @Notyourthing when i answered it ,the question was different..well i was busy..but now u already got the answer

Answer (score 0):

i've compile and run the program using [this site](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) with some little changes and got this:
[image]

working just fine

the only change i've done is

```
printf ( "\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d",num1,num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16);
```

Comment: Oh man,have a look at my edit,I have already changed that,since the first comment,but I need to find row/column/diagonal sum....thank you anway..

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and run your application and it does not show any "num" before of a number. In fact, I cannot understand how you get that output if you are only printing number with %d.

I would just substitute the *\t* (tab space) with *\n* ( new line).  It should work as you expect.

Comment: I have already changed that,since the first comment,but I need to find row/column/diagonal sum....thank you anway.

Comment: can I use an array? The best thing should be a matrix,  the code would more clean. :D

Comment: Haha ,no,in the assignment it says : No arrays ...but jpw already helped me.Thank you :)